# Weird behaviour with Object.assign

Tags: javascript, assign

I've stuck with the strange behaviour of assignment in javascript.

in this code

```
state = Object.assign({}, state, {
         [area]: Object.assign({}, state[area], {
           [name] : Object.assign({}, state[area][name], {
             selected:  [value]
           })
         })
       })

console.log(state) //state[area][name].selected is unchanged!
```

but if I try to console log Object.assign

```
console.log(Object.assign({}, state, {
              [area]: Object.assign({}, state[area], {
                [name] : Object.assign({}, state[area][name], {
                  selected:  [value]
                })
              })
           })); 
//it returns object with value in obj[area][name].selected, as expected
```

What do I wrong?

**EDIT:**
[image: wat]

Comment: I cannot find an issue here, the code works fine (see http://jsbin.com/ceburo/edit?js,console). The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: The funny thing about `console.log` is that the output is *live*. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(state, null, '  '))` at your last line instead

Comment: Thank you for comments! I think the question is exhausted. My problem not in that thing with console.log . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign works normally.
In this case, the problem was that console.log displays not actual data, but the reference to the object.
My real problem was in mutating state (array.pop()) in some react component.